# ctypes: structure, size_t field

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to implement python-to-c binding via `ctypes` for `libnfc`.
I have a structure, here is a wrong variant:

```
class nfc_iso14443a_info(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('abtAtqa',  c_uint8 * 2),
        ('btSak',    c_uint8),
        ('szUidLen', c_uint8 * 8),
        ('abtUid',   c_uint8 * 10),
        ...
```

At some moment during debug session it looks like that:
[image]

The problem here is that I want `szUidLen` to be 64-bit unsigned integer equal to 7. More precisely, it must match `size_t  szUidLen;` from `nfc-types.h`. So i tried an obvious variant and changed `c_uint8 * 8` to `c_size_t` and it doesn't work:

```
class nfc_iso14443a_info(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('abtAtqa',  c_uint8 * 2),
        ('btSak',    c_uint8),
        ('szUidLen', c_size_t),
        ('abtUid',   c_uint8 * 10),
        ...
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you copy the C struct definition into your question, or at least link to the file somewhere?

Comment: Also, can you put the actual values in text instead of a screenshot? It would be helpful to be able to, e.g., copy that huge number so I can turn it to hex and see if it’s just endian-swapped or off by one byte or the like.

Comment: I think the problem here may be packing. When you put a uint8*8 field, that aligns like uint8, so you end up with bytes 3-11; when you put a size_t, that aligns like size_t, so you get bytes 8-16. Try adding `_pack_=1` to the Structure class and see what that does. (This probably isn’t actually the right answer, unless this isn’t really a C in-memory struct but a network packet or file format chunk, but at least it will verify or rule out the issue.)

Comment: @abarnert 1. Thanks - it works! 2. I don't get why pack is needed: structure is defined on line 185 here: https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/include/nfc/nfc-types.h#L185 There is no packing as far as I can see. 3. - it only works when _pack_ = 1 and doesn't work if it is 2 or more. Why? Anyway, could you please copy your comments to the answer so I will be able to accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert I might be blind. `# pragma pack(1)` is there.

Comment: It seems like you pretty clearly understand the problem, but someone else searching for a similar issue might not. You want to write an answer yourself, close the question as a typo, or have me write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the C struct you're trying to map is packed, as (tersely) explained in the [Structure/union alignment and byte order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order) section of the docs:

> By default, Structure and Union fields are aligned in the same way the C compiler does it. It is possible to override this behavior be specifying a `_pack_` class attribute in the subclass definition. This must be set to a positive integer and specifies the maximum alignment for the fields. This is what `#pragma pack(n)` also does in MSVC.

That only makes sense if you already know about packing and alignment in C, but it's not that complicated.

By default, C structure elements are aligned to start on nice boundaries. For example, a 32-bit int following an 8-bit int doesn't run from bytes 1-4, it runs from bytes 4-7 (and bytes 1-3 are unused padding). So, `ctypes` follows the same rules.

That means that, while `szUidLen` runs from bytes 3-10 when it's defined as an array of 8-bit ints, it gets aligned to bytes 8-15 (or 4-11, depending on your compiler) when it's defined as a 64-bit int. You can see this by printing out `nfc_iso14443a_info.szUidLen.offset`.

So, the first one gets the bytes `7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`, which is little-endian int64 for `7`, while the second one gets the bytes `0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d, e`, where `abcde` are the first 5 bytes of the next field, which is little-endian int64 for some huge number (unless the next field happens to be 0).

Of course you don't want to just guess that this is the problem. If you based your `Structure` on a `struct` from a C header, this can only be true if the header or the compile flags specify some non-default packing, like the `#pragma pack(1)` used by MSVC. If you based your `Structure` on something like an RFC packet description, the alignment is not even according to C rules, but is defined somewhere in the documentation you're reading (although protocol RFCs almost always use 1-byte alignment).

Anyway, the docs don't explain the problem very well, but they explain the solution:

```
class nfc_iso14443a_info(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('abtAtqa',  c_uint8 * 2),
        ('btSak',    c_uint8),
        ('szUidLen', c_size_t),
        ('abtUid',   c_uint8 * 10),
        ...
```

Now `szUidLen` runs from bytes 3-10, but it's interpreted as a 64-bit int instead of an array of 8-bit ints.

Answer (score -2):

```
from ctypes import *
c_size_t = c_unit64
```

and go ahead
You **may** need to specify `._pack_=1` too (if your compiler generates code that way) **before** defining `_fields_`.

**Update:** There is ready made `c_size_t` (and `c_ssize_t`) type in `ctypes`.

**Note:** `(c_char * 8)` is *not* equal to `c_int64` or `c_long` because of possible alignment issues (`c_char` fields are not aligned). `ctypes.alignment(c_type)` may give you a hint on how *c_type* is aligned:

```
In [7]: c.alignment(c.c_char * 8), c.alignment(c.c_size_t)
Out[7]: (1, 8)
```